# Pointer to function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

What do this mistakes mean? Why when I make all the types double, it doesn't show the same mistakes?

> C2556 'int div(int,int)': overloaded function differs only by return
>   type from 'div_t div(int,int)'
>  C2371  'div': redefinition;
>   different basic types
>  C2491   'div': definition of dllimport
>   function not allowed
>    C2664  'int calculate(int,int,int (__cdecl
>   *)(int,int))': cannot convert argument 3 from 'overloaded-function' to 'int (__cdecl *)(int,int)'

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

int subs(int x, int y) {
    return x - y;
}

int mult(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
}

int div(int x, int y) {
    return x / y;
}
int calculate(int x, int y, int(*func)(int, int)) {
    return func(x, y);
}
void main() {
    cout<<"Sum:"<< calculate(8, 4, sum)<<endl;
    cout << "Subs:" << calculate(8, 4, subs) << endl;
    cout << "Mult:" << calculate(8, 4, mult) << endl;
    cout << "Div:" << calculate(8, 4, div) << endl;
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` strikes again! Remove it. There''s a good reason that standard library names are in `std`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists a `div` function in `stdlib.h` standard header that is included from `iostream`, so your overload is in conflict with.

One way is to use your own namespace (using namespaces is always a good idea), like this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace my {    
  int sum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
  }      
  int subs(int x, int y) {
    return x - y;
  }      
  int mult(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
  }     
  int div(int x, int y) {
    return x / y;
  }
  int calculate(int x, int y, int(*func)(int, int)) {
    return func(x, y);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Sum:"  << my::calculate(8, 4, my::sum)  << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Subs:" << my::calculate(8, 4, my::subs) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Mult:" << my::calculate(8, 4, my::mult) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Div:"  << my::calculate(8, 4, my::div)  << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Of course you can use some shorter alternative with `using`:

```
...
namespace my { ... }
using my;
...
  std::cout << "Sum:"  << my::calculate(8, 4, sum)  << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Subs:" << my::calculate(8, 4, subs) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Mult:" << my::calculate(8, 4, mult) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Div:"  << my::calculate(8, 4, my::div)  << std::endl; // scoped to eliminate ambiguity
```

Answer (score 1):

The `div` function was already declared by someone else (`#include<iostream>`) hence the overloading errors. Change your function name, or arguments (number/ type) to fix or encapsulate it in a namespace (as suggested by Jean-Baptiste Yunès).

Answer (score 0):

```
C2556 'int div(int,int)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'div_t div(int,int)'
C2371 'div': redefinition; different basic types
C2491 'div': definition of dllimport function not allowed
```

These all describe that a function like your `div` is already known about by the compiler.

Most likely [cppreference : div](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/div/)

The C++ system only differentiates a function by its calling parameters.  This means that the first error occurs.

The second describes (I think) different attributes, and the third means that the other div is in a library.

```
C2664 'int calculate(int,int,int (__cdecl *)(int,int))': cannot convert argument 3 from 'overloaded-function' to 'int (__cdecl *)(int,int)'
```

This makes `sum` look like it is declared in a class, so is not quite the same structure as it appears.  Please confirm.